# Azure AKS nginx/nginx-ingress:3.1.0 load balancer configuration problem

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

This is a new Azure AKS deployment via Terraform and manual troubleshooting.

Environment:

- Deployed test service aks-helloworld-two
- AKS Kubernetes version 1.24.6
- NGINX-Ingress v3.1.0 - nginx-ingress-controller ip x.x.x.63
  -- Deployed via terraform helm_release mostly default
- We do not use ingresses but use virtualserver and virtualserverroute CRDs
- kubernetes_service loadbalancer deploy. All traffic should hit this and routed to the ingress-controller.load balancer ip  x.x.x.62
- DNS is configured for service and pointing to the ingress-controller external ip

Whats working:
Current we can hit the aks-helloworld-two service no problem everything is up but traffic is flowing directly to the ingress-controller cluter ip and it should be going thru the load balancer service.

Goal:
Configure virtualserver and virtualserverroute to use the loadbalancer cluster ip #.#.#.62

Problem:
**Unable to find our how / where is picking up the ingress-controller ip.** I need to change the VS/VSR to use the loadbalancer IP

- kubectl get vs/vsr -A output shows the IP of the nginx-ingress-controller and not the load balancer.

[image: kubectl get vs/vsr output]

Everything works fine when traffic is routed thru the controller IP but not to the load balancer because of the vs/vsr configuration

[image: nginx-ingress and lb]

**virtualserver and virtualserver route yaml**

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld-two
  namespace: aks-helloworld-two
spec:
  host: aks-helloworld-two.dev.myloancare.internal
  # tls:
  #   secret: {{ .Values.virtual_server_secret }}
  routes:
  - path: /
    route: aks-helloworld-two
---
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServerRoute
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld-two
  namespace: aks-helloworld-two
spec:
  host: aks-helloworld-two.dev.myloancare.internal
  upstreams:
  - name: aks-helloworld-two
    service: aks-helloworld-two
    port: 80
  subroutes:
  - path: /
    action:
      pass: aks-helloworld-two
```

NGINX-ingress-controller YAML

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  uid: ba813380-5ac4-4cc0-888d-19351e607e50
  resourceVersion: '49682858'
  creationTimestamp: '2023-04-07T16:05:37Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 3.1.0
    helm.sh/chart: nginx-ingress-0.17.0
  annotations:
    creationTimestamp: '2023-04-07T16:05:37Z'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nginx-ingress
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: nginx-ingress
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: 'true'
  finalizers:
    - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  managedFields:
    - manager: terraform-provider-helm_v2.9.0_x5
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2023-04-07T16:05:37Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/version: {}
            f:helm.sh/chart: {}
        f:spec:
          f:allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: {}
          f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
          f:ports:
            .: {}
            k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
            k:{"port":443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
          f:selector: {}
          f:sessionAffinity: {}
          f:type: {}
    - manager: cloud-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2023-04-07T16:06:37Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:finalizers:
            .: {}
            v:"service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup": {}
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
      subresource: status
    - manager: kubectl-edit
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2023-04-07T16:36:21Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            f:creationTimestamp: {}
            f:service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: {}
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2023-04-12T15:24:26Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31328
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      nodePort: 30353
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx-ingress
  clusterIP: 10.0.64.133
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.0.64.133
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  healthCheckNodePort: 31323
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 172.18.32.63
```